# What is the preferred method to requesting enabling video embedding in an SE site's posts?

Tags: support, posting, videos

I have seen various meta questions either asking for a specific site to have video embedding turned on or discussing which sites have it turned on, but nothing about how to request it.

What is the preferred method for requesting this?

If there is no such policy, then consider this a request for "The Great Outdoors"

There was a question about whether a certain tool for igniting laboratory gas fires could work for starting a conventional wood fire. A simple "Yes, should work" is not a great answer, so I bought the tool just to make a video demonstration to test and verify for a proper answer.

That answer is [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/20540/12799).

I tried to embed a video by entering the proper html, and that didn't work. I have read in meta here that I should just enter the YouTube link on a line by itself, but I also see that "The Great Outdoors" is not listed as a site with this feature enabled.

I have made videos for other answers on that site too.

Comment: You can convert the video to .gif, this works, see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315993/auto-rendering-of-links-stops-working-after-the-fifth-link-or-does-it

Answer (score 4):

First, post a question on [the site's own Meta](https://outdoors.meta.stackechange.com) to make sure the rest of the community agrees with you. Be sure to provide *several* examples from posts which would benefit from this feature.

Second, enabling features like this comes with a [performance penalty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279637/295232) *for all Q&A pages on the site*, not just those with videos. Therefore, the Community Managers may decide not to honour the request, even if there's overwhelming support within the local community.

Comment: I posted on that site's meta, and their most active user linked me to SE meta information about embedded videos. I will make that meta.TGO Q&A into a broader discussion about the issues you raise here.

Comment: Concerning the issues you raise: That is interesting and something I was not aware of. I assume it is because every post gets auto-scanned for embedded videos to process them. I would assume (possibly incorrectly) that this performance penalty is a low percentage of the overall performance of the site. Do we have any information about the severity of the performance penalty we are talking about?

Comment: I'm on mobile right now and can't find the post (by an employee) where this was mentioned.

Comment: Obviously a video would be much preferable to an animated gif, but since those are already allowed: I assume a gif has no more performance issue than any other image (other than the fact that it will have more data), is that correct? Or will a gif have any significant performance penalty as well?

Comment: The meta post on outdoor.se has been done, now how do we ask a CM?